# Spring messaging websockets - how to call setMessageCodec

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am trying to use Spring websockets with `Genson` instead of `Jackson`. When I try and connect from a client I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A SockJsMessageCodec is required but not available: Add Jackson 2 to the classpath, or configure a custom SockJsMessageCodec.
```

It would appear I need to set a custom message codec.

I can see that a `.setMessageCodec` method appears on the `TransportHandlingSockJsService` but I can't see anywhere in the configuration options where I can actually set it.

I think the the `.setMessageCodec` method should be present on the `SockJsServiceRegistration` class so it can be set from configuration...but it isn't...any ideas?

**EDIT:** I believe this is a bug so have raised: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12091

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11184.

It looks like that you could implement it by overriding the configureMessageConverters method in WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.

Comment: I've already done that to convert the messages using Genson, but this question is actually about configuring a converter (they call it codec) for sockjs messages.